# How do you import local modules in the browser context with Playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright, sveltekit, dynamic-import

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

`../src/Foo/Bar.ts` is a local typescript file

The code in the file is meant to run in a browser context (it accesses `WebSockets`), so I need to run it in `page.evaluate`

```
page.evaluate( async () => {
    const { namedExportExample } = await import('../src/Foo/Bar;)

    // ...
});
```

I get `page.evaluate: TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier` and I'm not surprised, I'm not sure how the browser can evaluate that import, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this if possible?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure how the browser can evaluate that import, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this if possible?

You can't import modules for reasons explained by @max-schmitt. But Playwright's "Context" provides a way to inject new functions in the browser instance.

```
browserContext.exposeFunction(name, callback)
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-expose-function

###### Example

```
import * as crypto from "node:crypto" 

const browser = await chromium.launch(...)
const context = await browser.newContext()
    
// !!! Exposing a new function !!!
await context.exposeFunction("sha256", text => crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text).digest("hex")) 

const page = await context.newPage()
await page.goto(URL)

...
await someBox.evaluate((box : HTMLElement) => {
  console.log("!!!", window["sha256"]) // available !!!
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Playwright scripts run in your Playwright environment. Your page
> scripts run in the browser page environment. Those environments don't
> intersect, they are running in different virtual machines in different
> processes and even potentially on different computers.

In your scenario you try to import your file inside the page, which does not know anything about where to import that file. You need to stringify your function and pass it over the page to evaluate it.

See here for more information: https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating

Comment: Also, not sure about the Playwright piece, but if you're just trying to make sure the browser is available, you can do
```javascript
import { browser } from '$app/env';
if (browser) {
  // client-only code here
}
```
Or run inside `onMount()`
Source: https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#integrations-how-do-i-use-a-client-side-only-library-that-depends-on-document-or-window

Comment: Thanks. A major issue though, is that it seems some code can only be imported on the browser (e.g. it references window when importing). Other than with dynamic imports, I don't know if there's a way to deal with that.